# UFT/QTP dynamical url

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, uft14

i have this problem, an "url" has a "token" which generates a random number.
When i try to manipulate an object in this "url" during the run session, UFT doesn't recognize the object because the "url" change.

For example:

record::

```
Browser("url").Page("dynamicalUrl").WebButton("cancel").Click 
'The url value of Page( "dynamicalUrl") is for example: https://example.com/token=542654364678
```

Run Session::

UFT crashes in the step, because it doesn't recognize objects and the url value of Page( "dynamicalUrl") changes to: https://example.com/token=987757858

Is there any solution to this?, if someone know how to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is a Bad Practice to use the URL as a Page identififer. Try to use the title property instead.

In case you need the URL, use it as a Regular Expression. If your token is just numbers than the regexp is something like:

```
https://example.com/token=\d+
```

Generally speaking whatever is a dynamic part in a Property you need to use Regular Expressions for that

Comment: This was another solution, for my problem.
Thank you @BelaTamasJozsa

Answer (score 4):

if you only need the cancel button try to make the object dynamic
Use the spy to review properties and select the most appropriate ones.

```
Browser("index:=0").Page("name:=Page").WebButton("name:=Cancel")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to have any description for `Page` objects. Every `Browser` has only one `Page`, the reason UFT has this object at all is to create manageable object repositories.